# Developing ipad apps

Tags: ios, ipad, intel

i have done android dev. in the past.I want to start working on developing ipad apps. I installed xcode 3.0 on my mac. My mac is 10.5.8. It runs Intel Core Duo. I have googled on this and i found that in order to develop ipad apps one must have snowleopard  and it runs on 10.6 or higher. So, should  i buy new OS?But again the snow leopard OS requires Intel Core 2 Duo. Or any Mac with Intel is OK? I have more questions(reg. iOS SDK) but i got to find solution for this first. Please tell me what are my options.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is primarily a question about Mac OS X, not about iPad development.

Comment: Not really, it is about both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Core 2 Duo is needed for its 64 bit architecture.  64 bit is required to run Grand Central Dispatch which is included used in the iOS SDK for SL.  Long answer short - yes you will need a Core 2 Duo running Snow Leopard at a minimum.  My suggestion is to get something that will run Lion also.  I am a dev and love the applications saved state feature with Xcode running on Lion.

Comment: @EIJay.Thanks for the information. That was my question reg. h/w.Now coming to s/w for developing ipad apps. I require iOS SDK and iOS simulator. Do these come when i install the latest version of XCode?Bcoz while searching for the appropriate Xcode for my mac, i came across xcode 3.1.2 and with that iOS sdk.So if i have the xcode,iOS sdk and iOS simulator installed on a SL with Intel Core 2 duo can i get started developing ipad apps? I have done some basic Objective-C coding on Xcode 3.0 in cocoa fmwk.Will that help?can you suggest me some good ipad dev. books to buy?

Comment: Xcode comes with the SDK and the simulator.  Go with Xcode 4.3 (the latest version) free from the App store.  As far as learning resources, the Stanford iTunes U sessions are awesome and here : http://www.raywenderlich.com/  I am not big into books.

Comment: @EIJay. Ok so i don't have to install them separately. Great. But i dlded the latest Xcode 4.3 and tried to install it on my Intel Core Duo lpard mac. But it says it's not built for this archtture. I also read that Xcode 4.0 is no longer available for SL. Inorder to get that i have to be a paid developer ($99)????
 So can i buy SL (29.99 ) and then upgrade the SL to lion on this h/w? Then if i install Xcode 4.3 on this will it work?or i should go and buy a new mac (:(). Because, you told earlier that SL with Core 2 Duo is minimum. Can i change the processor to Intel core 2 duo on a mac?

Comment: You have to have at least a Core 2 Duo for the latest Xcode.  You do not have to be a paid developer to download and install Xcode only to put applications on a device or in the app store.  You can run them on the simulator for free.

Comment: @EIJay. Gotcha.So for the latest XCode i need a new processor.Period. What if i want to use my old mac. I used Xcode 3.0 the other day but i couldn't see iPhone OS application there while creating a new proj in XCode. So in short for this mac i can only develop Mac OS x applications...not ipad apps?If i can, what is the xcode i need to install (like u said iOS comes with XCode automatically). For iOS apps i need to have SL with Intel core 2 duo. Then i can get the version for XCode and work with it.Correct??

Comment: Correct, although if you are going to have to get a newer Mac anyway, get something that works well with Lion.

Comment: @EIJay. Thanks a ton for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: @EIJay . I got a new question. So, i want to buy a new mac mini. I am new to apple. So is mac mini like a CPU on windows machine.What about the monitor?should i purchase it separately?OR can i connect it to my mac with 10.5.8 intel core duo?I also have a samsung sa300/sa350 monitor.can i connect the mini to this?